# Creating lightweight documents

Tags: pdf-generation

Konica Bizhub scanner and printer has ability to create lightweight pdf files in 300 DPI color mode (it is called compact mode).

Such a file is really small (up to 200 KB). When You zoom in it looks it is a 2 color picture,
however containing color parts (if any).

As a programmer, I am looking for the way of creating such a file from "raw" scanned image (bmp, tiff, etc) to reduce drastically the output image size, but generally to achieve something what Konica does.

Can anyone suggest what operation I should perform on the raw image to achieve something similar?

Or maybe there is a 3rd party library to be used for such a occasion?

Comment: @KJ Here is a sample scanned file from konica: (https://transfer.sh/hYiUT7/test300DPI.pdf)

Comment: @KJ Thanks for sharing these. Do you know the way I can follow to achieve something like from native scan? Manually or using 3rd party software? I am curious how are those buffers created from the scan ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a Software Programming emulation exercise we need to take into account both how scanning firmware and PDF software can approach the task.

Background info
Scanners use several methods to hold the page data, so a "Camera" type scanner, will take a full page screenshot at maximum RAW resolution, where as "All-in-one" scanners may gulp a full width and dump as bands of data, OR parse side to side one pixel line at a time and combine into a full "Page" during file compression phase. There are other methods such as a fixed head WIDE carriage "CCD camera" is static and the media is moved over the head, then pixels stored line by line.

In most cases a large amount of memory is required to buffer a fully uncompressed scanned page.

The uncompressed "Bitmap Image" has no strict format but can be converted to lossless or lossy images.
[image]

It would appear from the sample, without reading the manual, that in this case the buffer is parsed for monochromatic areas which are then converted into a 2 colour bitmask, at one lossless high resolution (300 dpi density compressed to CCITT G4) and the remaining area is stored as lossy full colour compressed Jpeg at a lower density (150 dpi equivalent)

Then the Jpeg is used as a backdrop with the CCITT areas over-stamped on that. Here is the point where the images are defined in order it is low order object (#3) but written late in the process after all other page related zones have been defined.

```
3 0 obj
<</JI1Obj1 5 0 R
/TI1Obj1 7 0 R
/TI1Obj2 9 0 R
/TI1Obj3 11 0 R
>>
```

We can interpret that as

- /Jpeg1 Object 1 = Object 5  = /Width 1240 /Height 1754 /BitsPerComponent 8 /ColorSpace /DeviceRGB
- /TIff1 Object 1 = Object 7  = /CCITTFaxDecode ... /Width 1912 /Height 464 /BitsPerComponent 1 ... /ImageMask true
- /TIff1 Object 2 = Object 9  = /CCITTFaxDecode ... /Width 1904 /Height 1172 /BitsPerComponent 1 ... /ImageMask true
- /TIff1 Object 3 = Object 11 = /CCITTFaxDecode ... /Width 1904 /Height 563 /BitsPerComponent 1 ... /ImageMask true

What is not so obvious is how the single colours are defined in the masking of the page.

That is done in the placement

```
4 0 obj
<</Length 503>>
stream
q
595.200 0.000 0.000 841.680 0.000 0.000 cm
/JI1Obj1 Do
Q
0.957 0.396 0.388 rg
q
458.880 0.000 0.000 111.360 71.040 517.200 cm
/TI1Obj1 Do
Q
0.110 g
q
456.960 0.000 0.000 281.280 71.040 58.320 cm
/TI1Obj2 Do
Q
0.133 g
q
456.960 0.000 0.000 128.640 71.040 640.080 cm
/TI1Obj3 Do
Q
```

So the multicolour low res jpg is used first as the body, then the colour is set to a red [image] with mask overlay.
Then set to charcoal grey/blue 1 [image] for one image
and a different average ink colour charcoal grey/blue 2 [image]

***Thus to build such a compact format is relatively simple just knowing the placement areas and their average ink colours.***

Answer (score 1):

That's what I have been looking for is called: "Mixed raster content" (MRC).
[Wikipedia MRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_raster_content).
There are a few libraries out there in internet that support pdf compression.